# Why doesn't this getter for a property work?

Tags: javascript, getter

I'm trying to add a getter for a property defined on `Person`, so I can do `test.fullName`. The problem is, when I log `test.fullName`, it's undefined. Why does the getter work properly?

```
function Person(name, surname, yearOfBirth){
this.name = name,
this.surname = surname,
this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth };

Object.defineProperty(Person, 'fullName', {
    get: function(){
        return this.name +' '+ this.surname
    }
});

var test = new Person("test", "test", 9999);
console.log(test.fullName);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to define the property on the `Person`'s *prototype* property, so it's inherited on all instances.

```
Object.defineProperty(Person.prototype, 'fullName', {
    get: function() {
        return this.name +' '+ this.surname
    }
});
```

Adding a property to just `Person` will make it static. You must do it on `Person.prototype`. You can read more at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes). Per the link:

> Prototypes are the mechanism by which JavaScript objects inherit features from one another

Thus, for all `Person` instances to inherit all properties such as `fullName`, define the property on `Person.prototype`.

Also, you are using commas instead semicolons. Use semicolons to terminate statements, not commas:

```
this.name = name;
this.surname = surname;
this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
```

Answer (score 4):

You're defining the `fullName` property on `Person`. You should define it on `Person.prototype`, so it's inherited by instances:

```js
function Person(name, surname, yearOfBirth) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
};

Object.defineProperty(Person.prototype, 'fullName', {
    get: function() {
        return this.name + ' ' + this.surname
    }
});

var test = new Person("test", "test", 9999);
console.log(test.fullName);
```

---

Side note: Don't use commas where you should have semicolons, as in the `Person` constructor. I've fixed that above as well.

Comment: @AndrewLi: ? You mean when I added the snippet? :-)

Comment: @AndrewLi: :-) I wonder if there's a dupetarget for closing the question...

Comment: Hi @T.J.Crowder thanks for your help! And a little bit of explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Define it on the prototype.

```
Object.defineProperty(Person.prototype, 'fullName', {
    get() {
        return `${this.name} ${this.surname}`;
    }
});
```